# How to transform properties in a RXJS Observable

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I have to transform an object property in a RXJS Observable.
This works using the "map" operator.
The problem occurs when I subscribe twice to the same observable: the property is transformed twice

I have tried to use the "share" operator and multiple variations but nothing seems to work

#### Code Example:

```
    const source = of(
      { id: 1, name: 'John' },
    );

    const personObservable = source.pipe(
      map(person => { 
        person.name = person.name + '_test'; return person; 
      }),
    );

    personObservable.subscribe(
      person => console.log('first: ', person)
    );

    personObservable.subscribe(
      person => console.log('second: ', person)
    );
```

#### Expected result:

```
first:  John_test
second:  John_test
```

#### Actual result:

```
first:  John_test
second:  John_test_test
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because you are modifying same object instance twice. When your map would return a copy of that object it would not happen. Try this:

```
const personObservable = source.pipe(
      map(person => ({
          ...person,
          name: person.name + '_test'
      })),
    );
```

You could also use `shareReplay` operator with your original mapping function:

```
const personObservable = source.pipe(
  map(person => { 
        person.name = person.name + '_test'; return person; 
      }),
  shareReplay()
);
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-emh78g)

Comment: I was going to answer the same thing, here's a stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-udvzdt

Comment: You could use the "more concise" {...person, name: person.name + '_test'}.

Comment: Thank you, this works but this code is hard to maintain. If in the future I add another property to the Person object, i need to edit this code too. I know there are multiple strategies to clone an object but it would be nice if there is an RXJS operator in order to conditionally map only the first time.

@S.Pellegrino your answer works fine! Thank you.

Comment: @Zerotwelve added another example how to do it. With `shareReplay` the `map` function is run only once and the result is replayed and shared.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to **use `Observable.create` or `new Observable()` to create your Observable.**

`of` creates a multicast Observable. `new Observable` will result in the creation of a cold, unicast Observable, which emits a new instance of your object for each Observer.

```
const source = new Observable((subscriber) => {
  subscriber.next({ id: 1, name: 'John' });
  subscriber.complete();
});

const personObservable = source.pipe(
  map(person => { 
    person.name = person.name + '_test'; return person; 
  }),
);

personObservable.subscribe(
  person => console.log('first: ', person)
);

personObservable.subscribe(
  person => console.log('second: ', person)
);
```

Working StackBlitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bdhjuo

I also recently wrote an article explaining hot and cold Observables, which you may find useful:

http://willtaylor.blog/rxjs-observables-hot-cold-explained/